# Ember 3.15, seperating components javascript from template files

Tags: ember.js, components, ember-octane

Is it possible to separate the templates .hbs from component class javascript .js  in Ember 3.15 Octane.

A folder structure like:

```
app/
   components/
     js/
     hbs/
```

Comment: It is possible. But not recommended. Why do you want this? You can just place your templates to `app/templates/component/component-name.js` and keep your `.js` where it is

Comment: Thanks @Lux for your comment. I was not sure that the classic structure works in 3.15. I can adapt that to my project.

Comment: `3.15` is *just* a minor release. Everything that worked in `3.0` should continue to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “classic” directory structure does separate component Javascript and template files, but not in the way you specified. Running `ember generate component component-name --component-structure classic --gc` would result in this structure (ignoring the `tests` directory):

```
app/
  components/
    component-name.js
    templates/
      component-name.hbs
```

If you really must have the directory structure you specified, you could accomplish it using a custom resolver. [Here](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/09/14/understanding-ember-s-resolver)’s a blog post that gives a high-level overview of that. I’d caution against that kind of thing, though, as it’s usually beneficial to stick with what most of the community uses, and in 3.15 that’s the `flat` component structure. What’s your use case?

Comment: Thank you, for your response. I did not know I could use the classic directory structure. This should solve it for me as it separates the js files from the hbs files. I just wasn't sure that the classic structure is supported in Octane. Thank you.